# Loop is not looping

Tags: bash, unix, ssh

I'm using the following script to loop through a list of servers then output free disk space info. SSH keys are already in place and working.

But it's only outputting the first server name, then existing...I'm stumped.

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
export PATH

while IFS='|' read hostname nickname; do
    echo "$hostname: $nickname"  
    ssh $hostname "df -Pkhl"

done < server-list.dat
```

And the list:

```
% cat server-list.dat
serverone|ONE
servertwo|TWO
serverthree|THREE
```

Comment: Does the host you are connecting to require a password?

Comment: No passwords are being used -- SSH keys, and these are working.

Comment: I'm pretty sure questions essentially the same as this have been asked, and answered, before.  Finding it, of course, will be hard -- unless the Related Questions list helps out, and it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you are attaching stdin to `server-list.dat`, but `ssh` also expects to read from stdin.

To solve this, you can open the file with a different descriptor:

```
while IFS='|' read -u 3 hostname nickname; do
    echo "$hostname: $nickname"  
    ssh $hostname "df -Pkhl"

done 3< server-list.dat
```

The use of `-u 3` and `3<` opens `server-list.dat` as file descriptor 3.

Comment: Greg, you rock, that works perfectly. Thanks!